# Substitute a cls constructor with arg for one without

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest

`Cls().method()` is called by code in a pytest func.
How would I substitute `Cls(db_session)` for the cls instance using `patch`?

I was thinking along the following:

```
with patch('tests.functional.test_file.Cls', Cls(db_session)):
    code that calls Cls().method()
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about what you are trying to do and maybe add some context?

Comment: I have an SQLAlchemy session object in the scope of the test func.  I want to pass that to the mapper class constructor.  Otherwise, it attempts to get its own session.